# How much of what the second couple said was planned, and how much was improvised?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-overnight

In [*The Overnight*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Overnight) [2015], it quickly transpires that the second couple (Kurt and Charlotte) have a motive for inviting the first couple (Alex and Emily).

How far did they plan ahead? And how much are they just going with the flow?